# How to solve problem with parsing html file with cyrillic symbol?

Tags: python, parsing, lxml

I have some html file with span elements:

```
<html>
<body>
<span class="one">Text</span>some text</br>
<span class="two">Привет</span>Текст на русском</br>
</body>
</html>
```

To get "some text" :

```
# -*- coding:cp1251 -*-
import lxml
from lxml import html

filename = "t.html"
fread = open(filename, 'r')
source = fread.read()

tree = html.fromstring(source)
fread.close()


tags = tree.xpath('//span[@class="one" and text()="Text"]') #This OK
print "name: ",tags[0].text
print "value: ",tags[0].tail

tags = tree.xpath('//span[@class="two" and text()="Привет"]') #This False

print "name: ",tags[0].text
print "value: ",tags[0].tail
```

This show:

```
name: Text
value: some text

Traceback: ... in line `tags = tree.xpath('//span[@class="two" and text()="Привет"]')`
    ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## lxml

(As observed, this is a bit dodgy between system encodings and apparently doesn't work properly in Windows XP, though it did in Linux.)

I got it to work by decoding the source string - `tree = html.fromstring(source.decode('utf-8'))`:

```
# -*- coding:cp1251 -*-
import lxml
from lxml import html

filename = "t.html"
fread = open(filename, 'r')
source = fread.read()

tree = html.fromstring(source.decode('utf-8'))
fread.close()


tags = tree.xpath('//span[@class="one" and text()="Text"]') #This OK
print "name: ",tags[0].text
print "value: ",tags[0].tail

tags = tree.xpath('//span[@class="two" and text()="Привет"]') #This is now OK too

print "name: ",tags[0].text
print "value: ",tags[0].tail
```

This means that the actual tree is all `unicode` objects. If you just put the xpath parameter as a `unicode` it finds 0 matches.

## BeautifulSoup

I prefer to use BeautifulSoup for any of this sort of stuff, anyway. Here is my interactive session; I saved the file in cp1251.

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> filename = '/tmp/cyrillic'
>>> fread = open(filename, 'r')
>>> source = fread.read()
>>> source  # Scary
'<html>\n<body>\n<span class="one">Text</span>some text</br>\n<span class="two">\xcf\xf0\xe8\xe2\xe5\xf2</span>\xd2\xe5\xea\xf1\xf2 \xed\xe0 \xf0\xf3\xf1\xf1\xea\xee\xec</br>\n</body>\n</html>\n'
>>> source = source.decode('cp1251')  # Let's try getting this right.
u'<html>\n<body>\n<span class="one">Text</span>some text</br>\n<span class="two">\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442</span>\u0422\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0442 \u043d\u0430 \u0440\u0443\u0441\u0441\u043a\u043e\u043c</br>\n</body>\n</html>\n'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
>>> soup  # OK, that's looking right now. Note the </br> was dropped as that's bad HTML with no meaning.
<html>
<body>
<span class="one">Text</span>some text
<span class="two">Привет</span>Текст на русском
</body>
</html>

>>> soup.find('span', 'one').findNextSibling(text=True)
u'some text'
>>> soup.find('span', 'two').findNextSibling(text=True)  # This looks a bit daunting ...
u'\u0422\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0442 \u043d\u0430 \u0440\u0443\u0441\u0441\u043a\u043e\u043c'
>>> print _  # ... but it's not, really. Just Unicode chars.
Текст на русском
>>> # Then you may also wish to get things by text:
>>> print soup.find(text=u'Привет').findParent().findNextSibling(text=True)
Текст на русском
>>> # You can't get things by attributes and the contained NavigableString at the same time, though. That may be a limitation.
```

At the end of that, it's possibly worth while considering trying `source.decode('cp1251')` instead of `source.decode('utf-8')` when you're taking it from the filesystem. lxml may actually work then.

Comment: I did it on Linux.  Hang on, I'll start up my XP VM and see if I can figure it out on XP.

Comment: Thanks Chris! Under XP this is ANSI files.

Comment: Actually, I don't have lxml installed in my VM and am too lazy to do so (reprehensible, I know). I'll add some BeautifulSoup code to my answer which I hope may suit you.

Comment: ) Ok, this is not problem. I'll try it under my Linux 2 hrs later. Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Try `source.decode('cp1251')` instead of `source.decode('utf-8')`. It might work. If not, play around with BeautifulSoup... it's fun, and you'll learn a bit, even if you don't succeed in getting what you want.

Comment: Thanks Chris. It's ok then i use BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
tree = html.fromstring(source.decode('utf-8'))
```

and

```
tags = tree.xpath('//span[@class="two" and text()="%s"]' % u'Привет' )
```

Answer (score 1):

I got same error for XML generating with lxml. Found solution here: http://lethain.com/stripping-illegal-characters-from-xml-in-python/

I just made:

```
remove_re = re.compile(u'[\x00-\x08\x0B-\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F]')
etree_sub_el.text = remove_re.sub('', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested, but wrapping the call to `tags[0].tail` in the unicode() built-in function should do it: `unicode(tags[0].tail)`

Comment: Problem in this line: tags = tree.xpath('//span[@class="two" and text()="Привет"]')

Comment: Ok, well what about `text()=u"Привет"` and if that doesn't do it `text() = unicode("Привет")`

Comment: I tried these options.
The same result. My html file in ASCII format and python script in ASCII format. I tried convert its to UTF-8 but do nothing. (( Maybe I dont't understand some codecs routings?