# Find element by text in tag

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to parse some sites and have faced a problem with finding an element with xpath.

Do you know if there could be problems if the text you want to specify in xpath is not in English but e.g. in Russian?

let's say i want to find by such xpath

```
//*input[@value="text in Russian"]
```

Do I need to decode something or it is supposed to work and I need to solve the other problem??

update

It doesn't work even with explicit declaring like

```
'//*input[@value="%s"]' % u'text in Russian'
```

I will keep looking for other reasons.

Thx to all

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180987/how-to-solve-problem-with-parsing-html-file-with-cyrillic-symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my problem was not with decoding but with specifying the full xpath to the element.

I spotted that for pages with complex structure partial xpath work not so good and not always.

In my case it is like:

```
//form[@id="basket-form"]/div/div[@class="content-top-secondary-section"]/div/div/div[@data-id="price-summary"]/div/div/input[@value="text in Russian"]
```

Intead of initial simple declaration of the last part

```
//input[@value="text in Russian"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It should not be a problem and it should just work without decoding in Python 3.

**Working Example** — Tested with Python **3.4.3** and **3.5.1**

```
from lxml import html

html_content = '<div anything="который">text inside div</div>'

doc = html.fromstring(html_content)

tree = doc.xpath('//div[@anything="который"]')

print(tree[0].text)
```

Output:

```
text inside div
```

Comment: Then I have some other problem. For some reasons I can't press the button in this way